# Similar item Sub categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have two drop down list pulled from mysql using php

vendor

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

fault

- downtime
- tat
- hardware

vendor aaa & bbb share the same fault categories
 - downtime
 - tat
 - hardware

whereas ccc can only have

- downtime
- tat

My problem is, how to design a relationship in mysql db, so that data can be pulled like chain select?

Comment: What do you mean by "chain select". The usual way to design this could be `vendor (id, name)`, `fault (id, name)`, `vendor_fault (vendor_id, fault_id)`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte "chain select"-> by selecting the value from the first dropdown will filter the dropdown list items on the second dropdown

Comment: when you select **ccc** on the first dropdown then second dropdown show only **downtime,
tat** is this right condition

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i need